# Is there any way to fetch data in XML format from PostgreSQL table which has different field not the XML data type field?

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql

I want to fetch data from database in XML format using JDBC and Postgresql but data is stored  in  id,name, age format.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

Use a combination of [`xmlelement`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-xml.html) and [`xmlforest`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-xml.html) as follows.

Data sample

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t 
(id INTEGER, name TEXT, age INTEGER);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1,'John',25);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (2,'Jane',22);
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
  xmlelement(name person,
    xmlforest(id, name, age) 
  )
FROM t;
                        xmlelement                         
-----------------------------------------------------------
 <person><id>1</id><name>John</name><age>25</age></person>
 <person><id>2</id><name>Jane</name><age>22</age></person>
(2 Zeilen)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use Saxon's XSLT extension:

```
<persons>
   <sql:query connection="sql:connect(....)" table="t"/>
</persons>
```

http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!sql-extension

You've then got the XML into an XSLT stylesheet that can manipulate it into the final format you actually want.